# "flutter pub get" doesn't update. can anyone offer advice?

Tags: flutter

I have tried flutter doctor also deleting the bin, but no luck
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUq6D.png)

I am try to install a supabase package
I have checked the formatting several times on the pubspec.yaml it is good.

I have already reinstalled flutter also switched to stable version

I get an exit code 69 on vs code if this means anything

Comment: "build_rumour"?  Not "build_runner"?  Show your pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your attached image, the error showed that you tried to add unknown dependency named **build_rumour** that does not exist in pub.dev website, try to search by your self by searching on that website.

[Here the result](https://pub.dev/packages?q=build_rumour)

Just replace your package name (build_rumour) in *pubspec.yaml* file with correct package name.